# django angular load static files - image in assets folder get 404

Tags: django, angular, nginx, django-staticfiles

i have a assets/image folder in angular src folder and i left all of my images there, i have many component and child component that are using that images like `<img src"../../../assets/image/test.png">`,

i build my angular app and place all files to static folder , in nginx i point it to load from static folder and in django in template i used index.html to load the static files like below:
now my app will run but no file that have address like "../../../file" in angular load all get 404 like this :

```
http://hello.com/bird.65c8b9bce67b6a965a9c.png (error 404)
```

if i put a static keyword front of address it like `http://hello.com/static/bird.65c8b9bce67b6a965a9c.png`
image will load ..
how can i handle this issue?

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> site </title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'favicon.png' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.921a613cd46f44e0d5a0.css' %}"></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading .  .  .</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polyfills.b0205464c9bd4e7fe3b3.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scripts.59ed76cc23ba77b0ec72.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main.08947dd689f13d4027ea.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

also i aleady added

```
urlpatterns += static(base.STATIC_URL, document_root=base.STATIC_ROOT) + \
               static(base.MEDIA_URL, document_root=base.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to end of my urls.py and i run `python manage.py collectstatic`

nginx server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hello.com;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/vertical/academy;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
       #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/vertical/academy/academy.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that Angular is pointing the resources to Django's root.

You need to specify `resourcesOutputPath` parameter to `ng bulid` command:

```
ng build --output-path /path-to-django-app/static --resources-output-path static
```

So it will point to `http://hello.com/static/bird.65c8b9bce67b6a965a9c.png` intead of `http://hello.com/bird.65c8b9bce67b6a965a9c.png`

Note that resources output path is relative to output path.

See the **Options** section here: https://angular.io/cli/build

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking what to do about the expected behavior of Django with static files. The reason you get a 404 error for the file at `http://hello.com/bird.65c8b9bce67b6a965a9c.png` is because that file does not exist at that URL. Django serves all static files from the `/static/` subdomain, or a differently-named subdomain that you can define with `STATIC_URL` in your `settings.py`.

Here is the relevant documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to pass the static folder url in the window object, access it via typescript. Create a service for window object. That way you can easily access the data in any component in the app.

Also, do not add the hash value in the html file (for css and js) since that is bound to change. Use hashing false  in the bundler config.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the environment variables of Angular.

In your angular app under src/environments are two typescript files environment.ts and environment.prod.ts. You can define variables in these files which differ from the development environment to the production environment.

So you can add image sources as typescript strings like

```
<img [src]="imageURL" alt="my_image">
```

and define imageURL in your TS file as

```
//environments/environment is replaced with environments/environment.prod on ng build --prod
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment'

//staticURL is '' in environment.ts and '/static/' in environment.prod.ts
imageURL = environment.staticURL + 'assets/images/myimage.png'
```

You can learn more about environment variables [here](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/environment-variables-angular/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `Angular` and `Django`. My fixable solution was the one that `@Devesh Pradhan` provided.

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,<br>
// Custom path in my exemple.<br>
  djangoStaticpath: '/static/angular/images/'
};
```

So I've defined a path for the `production env`, while on the `develpment env` is just a empty string.
And the second trick was to add the background images in html using Angular style bindings.

```
"<div [style.background-image]="'url(' + imgSrc + 'test.png)'"></div>"
```

Here imgSrc is the djangoStaticpath value imported in the component.ts.